# Razer DeathAdder 2013 mouse jumps around the screen

Tags: razer-mouse

Sometimes, the cursor moves itself to the edges of the screen. I have to lift the mouse and put it down and then it works again. I have tried cleaning the sensor at the bottom; the only problem left that I can think of is the mouse mat (an unnamed; cheap one and rather small).

Could the mat causes this kind of problem? Is an official Razer mat required in order to use this mouse?

Comment: Flame stripes don't make a generic computer peripheral a gaming device. This is a question for Super User if anything, and better yet Razer support. Voting to close.

Comment: have you tried another surface?  The table?  A peice of paper?

Comment: @Keltari thanks. I tried a white paper sheet and it works properly. i guess it's the mousepad-related issue after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, the Razer Lachesis had a "jumping" problem which may or may not apply to the Death Adder.

A Razer mat is not required, but recommended. The Death Adder is an [Optical Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mouse) (as opposed to Laser) so you'll want a mat that's geared toward optical mice.

From the Razer Lachesis [FAQ](http://www.razersupport.com/gaming-mice/razer-lachesis/):

> **What type of mouse pad will work best with the Razer Lachesis?** 
>   We have found the Razer Lachesis to perform at its best with a hard mouse pad surface. We recommend the Razer Destructor, although any quality hard surface mouse pad will work as well.